# Is a bat kohen who has relations with a pasul (not marries) then forbidden from t'rumah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, sexuality, talmud-yerushalmi, masechet-yevamot, teruma

Is a bat kohen who has relations with a pasul (not marries) then forbidden from t'rumah? I ask this because I'm having trouble understanding Noam Yerushalmi's explanation of Yerushalmi Yevamot 8:6 in which he explains that it makes sense to say that an androgynous kohen who is married by an androgynous Yisrael would be nifsal from the t'rumah, but that it doesn't make sense to say that the same is true if the androgynous kohen is nivelet by the androgynous Yisrael. I don't understand the difference between if she is married and if she is nivelet.